# RegEx filter not working in Sublime Text search

Tags: javascript, regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to find all the camel case strings in a Sublime project that meet the following criteria:

- Begins with at least one lowercase letter, followed by at least one capital letter, followed by at least one lowercase letter or capital letter
- Appears between single quotes.
- Contains no spaces, numbers, or non-alphabetical characters.

Here is my expression:

`('[a-z]{1,}[A-Z]{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1,}')`

This works perfectly in the RegExr simulator, but in Sublime Text's search, it returns all kinds of strings, some in all caps, some all lowercase.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a *case sensitive* button you need to click?

Comment: If you are unsure of what  your options are, use `(?-i:\b[a-z]+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)`

Comment: @Alex K. You're a genius! Thank you.

Comment: I does work... I just tested it in Build 3126

Comment: @Wiktor, also very good, although I had to restore my single quotes. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest turning off case insensitivity inside the regex pattern with `(?-i)` or `(?-i:...)` to avoid issues with the options, and also using a `+` instead of `{1,}` increases readability (IMHO).

```
'(?-i)[a-z]+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+'
```

[image]

Even though the `Aa` (case sensitive search) is not enabled, the pattern is still handled in a case sensitive way.